# HTML5 header doesn't resize with nav menu

Tags: css, html

I've got this header:

```
<header>
    header 
    <br />
    <nav>
        <a href="index/" class="activeNav">Home</a>
        <a href="index/help/">Help</a>
        <a href="login/">Login</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

with this css:

```
header {
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    background: gold;
}

header nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

header nav>a{
    background-color: black;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px
}

header nav>a.activeNav{
    background-color: white;
}
```

But the bottom of the `nav` element doesn't align with the bottom of the `header` element. Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Mehhh...]

I know it looks bad but that's because I wanted to fix this first. So, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but isn't there a way to automatically resize the header without manually adding pixels or cutting of the nav?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply `display: inline-block` to your `header nav > a` elements.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/84Mau/5/)

Or you can apply `overflow: hidden` to your `header` element *(if you just want your `nav` to fit `header` by cutting inner elements)*.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/84Mau/)

Comment: Thanks! `display:inline-block` did it!

Answer (score 1):

These solutions will work, but they don't explain why this issue is occurring.

Anchors by default are inline elements, and their backgrounds can extend past their parents without forcing the parent to accommodate their height.

A more elegant solution that won't involve fiddling with pixels, which can be cumbersome if you implement a responsive design, is to specify the anchors as block-level elements and float them left:

```
header nav>a{
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```

However, now they are floated, you need to ensure the header will "clear" them - in other words extend its height to accommodate them. This will do the trick:

```
header:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84Mau/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding 5 pixels to the bottom `padding` of the `header` element.

Answer (score 0):

5 pixels need to be added as `padding` to the bottom of your `header`.
 **Like So:**

```
header {
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
  background: gold;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SimplyAzuma/s5aBr/) (added background for visibility)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is fixing by adding `overflow:hidden`. You can read about this issue in the web. It called "haslayout". Read about this to avoid this mistake at the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set `padding` to all directions but bottom, change it to this:

```
header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: gold;
}
```

OR you can use `overflow:hidden`

```
header {
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    background: gold;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```